# Canvas JS. Оптимальное рисование точек

Tags: javascript, canvas, оптимизация, 2d, webgl

Есть программа, в основе которой отрисовка разноцветных точек на экране:

```js
function fullScreen(elem) {
            if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
                elem.requestFullscreen();
            } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
            } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
                elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
            }
        }
        var ww = window.innerWidth;
        var wh = window.innerHeight;
        var myinterval = setInterval(function(){
        });
        var canvas;
        var ctx;
        var array_points = [];
        var cursor_power = 0.2;
        var arrow_power = 0.2;
        var spin_angle = 13;
        var finger = {
            val: 0.2
        }
        var lineto = false;
        var distribution = [];
        var limit_speed = 20;
        var mass = [0.5, 1.2];
        var color_a = [255, 0, 0];
        var color_b = [0, 0, 255];
        var col_r = [0, 255, false];
        var col_g = [0, 0, false];
        var col_b = [0, 255, true];
        var mouse = false;
        var arrows = [false, false, false, false];
        var spin = 0;
        var wall_decrement = 0.8;
        var speed = [-4, 4];
        var pxnpts = 700;
        var gravity_resistance = 2;
        var fps_loop = 60;
        var force_visualisation = false;
        var shuffle_distribution = true;
        var shuffle_generation = true;
        var inertion = true;
        var border = true;
        var flag = [false, false];
        function myRandom(x, y){
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (y - x + 1)) + x;
        }
        function FRandom(min, max) {
          return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
        }
        function getMass(percent){
            return percent*(mass[1] - mass[0]) + mass[0];
        }
        function clr_set(percent, colour){
            if(!window["col_" + colour][2]){
                return percent*(window["col_" + colour][1] - window["col_" + colour][0]) + window["col_" + colour][0];
            }
            else{
                return (1 - percent)*(window["col_" + colour][1] - window["col_" + colour][0]) + window["col_" + colour][0];
            }
        }
        function clr_create(percent){
            return 'rgb(' + (color_a[0]*percent + color_b[0]*(1 - percent)) + ', ' + (color_a[1]*percent + color_b[1]*(1 - percent)) + ', ' + (color_a[2]*percent + color_b[2]*(1 - percent)) + ')';
            //return 'rgb(' + clr_set(percent, 'r') + ', ' + clr_set(percent, 'g') + ', ' + clr_set(percent, 'b') + ')';
        }
        var lastCalledTime;
        var fps;
        function requestAnimFrame() {
            if(!lastCalledTime) {
                lastCalledTime = Date.now();
                fps = 0;
                return;
            }
            delta = (Date.now() - lastCalledTime)/1000;
            lastCalledTime = Date.now();
            fps = 1/delta;
        }
        function kut(ax, ay, bx, by){
            var at2 = Math.atan2(bx-ax, by-ay)*180/3.14159265;
            return (((at2<0) ? 360+at2 : at2) + 90 + spin)%360;
        }
        function accelerate_by_arrows(obj){
            var add_x = 0;
            var add_y = 0;
            if(arrows[0]){
                add_y -= arrow_power;
                flag[0] = true;
            }
            if(arrows[1]){
                add_x += arrow_power;
                flag[0] = true;
            }
            if(arrows[2]){
                add_y += arrow_power;
                flag[0] = true;
            }
            if(arrows[3]){
                add_x -= arrow_power;
                flag[0] = true;
            }
            if(inertion){
                obj.x.speed += add_x/obj.mass*(1 - Math.abs(obj.x.speed)/limit_speed);
                obj.y.speed += add_y/obj.mass*(1 - Math.abs(obj.y.speed)/limit_speed);
            }
            else{
                obj.x.speed = add_x/obj.mass*(1 - Math.abs(obj.x.speed)/limit_speed);
                obj.y.speed = add_y/obj.mass*(1 - Math.abs(obj.y.speed)/limit_speed);
            }
            obj.y.add += add_y;
            obj.x.add += add_x;
        }
        function accelerate_to_cursor(obj, x, y, force){
            /*var delta_x = x - obj.x.pos;
            var delta_y = y - obj.y.pos;
            var delta = Math.abs(delta_x) + Math.abs(delta_y);
            var add_x = force.val*(delta_x/delta)/obj.mass*(1 - Math.abs(obj.x.speed)/limit_speed);
            var add_y = force.val*(delta_y/delta)/obj.mass*(1 - Math.abs(obj.y.speed)/limit_speed);*/
            var angle = kut(obj.x.pos,obj.y.pos, x, y);
            var add_x = -force.val*Math.cos(angle*Math.PI/180)/obj.mass*(1 - Math.abs(obj.x.speed)/limit_speed);
            var add_y = force.val*Math.sin(angle*Math.PI/180)/obj.mass*(1 - Math.abs(obj.y.speed)/limit_speed);
            if(inertion){
                obj.x.speed += add_x*(Math.abs(obj.x.delta) < Math.abs(add_x) ? gravity_resistance : 1);
                obj.y.speed += add_y*(Math.abs(obj.y.delta) < Math.abs(add_y) ? gravity_resistance : 1);
            }
            else{
                obj.x.speed = add_x*(Math.abs(obj.x.delta) < Math.abs(add_x) ? gravity_resistance : 1);
                obj.y.speed = add_y*(Math.abs(obj.y.delta) < Math.abs(add_y) ? gravity_resistance : 1);
            }
            obj.x.delta = add_x;
            obj.y.delta = add_y;
            obj.y.add += add_y;
            obj.x.add += add_x;
        }
        function move(obj){
            obj.x.pos = obj.x.pos + obj.x.speed;
            obj.y.pos = obj.y.pos + obj.y.speed;
            if(border){
                if (obj.y.pos < 0) {
                    obj.y.pos = -obj.y.pos;
                    obj.y.speed = -obj.y.speed*wall_decrement;
                    obj.x.speed *= wall_decrement;
                }
                if (obj.y.pos > wh) {
                    obj.y.pos = wh - (obj.y.pos - wh);
                    obj.y.speed = -obj.y.speed*wall_decrement;
                    obj.x.speed *= wall_decrement;
                }
                if (obj.x.pos < 0) {
                    obj.x.pos = -obj.x.pos;
                    obj.x.speed = -obj.x.speed*wall_decrement;
                    obj.y.speed *= wall_decrement;
                }
                if (obj.x.pos > ww) {
                    obj.x.pos = ww - (obj.x.pos - ww);
                    obj.x.speed = -obj.x.speed*wall_decrement;
                    obj.y.speed *= wall_decrement;
                }
            }
            if(force_visualisation && (flag[0] || flag[1]) && (obj.y.add != 0 || obj.x.add != 0)){
                var increase = 40/((flag[0]?arrow_power:0) + (flag[1]?cursor_power:0));
                ctx.moveTo(obj.x.pos, obj.y.pos);
                ctx.lineTo(obj.x.pos + obj.x.add*increase, obj.y.pos + obj.y.add*increase);
            }
            else if(lineto){
                ctx.lineTo(obj.x.pos, obj.y.pos);
            }
            var percent = (obj.mass - mass[0])/(mass[1] - mass[0] + 0.000001);
            ctx.fillStyle = clr_create(percent);
            ctx.fillRect(obj.x.pos - 1, obj.y.pos - 1, 2, 2);
        }
        function Start(){
            inertion = true;
            var num_of_points = Math.round(ww*wh/pxnpts);
            //num_of_points = 1;
            clearInterval(myinterval);
            canvas = $('.canv').get(0);
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            array_points = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < num_of_points; i++){
                array_points[i] = {
                    x: {
                        pos: Math.random()/1*ww,
                        speed: FRandom(speed[0], speed[1]),
                        delta: 0,
                        add: 0,
                    },
                    y: {
                        pos: Math.random()/1*wh,
                        speed: FRandom(speed[0], speed[1]),
                        delta: 0,
                        add: 0,
                    },
                    mass: getMass((shuffle_generation ? (i % 2 ? i : num_of_points - i) : i)/num_of_points)
                };
            }
            myinterval = setInterval(function(){
                flag = [false, false];
                requestAnimFrame();
                ctx.clearRect(0,0,ww,wh);
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.strokeStyle = line;
                ctx.fillStyle = line;
                ctx.font = "22px arial";
                ctx.fillText("ctrl+h - Help", 5, 22);
                ctx.font = "17px arial";
                ctx.fillText("by Shumik", ww - 80, wh - 5);
                ctx.font = "17px arial";
                ctx.fillText(fps.toFixed(2) + " fps", 2, wh - 5);
                ctx.moveTo(array_points[0].x.pos, array_points[0].y.pos);
                for (var i = 0; i < array_points.length; i++) {
                    array_points[i].x.add = 0;
                    array_points[i].y.add = 0;
                    accelerate_by_arrows(array_points[i]);
                    if(mouse){
                        accelerate_to_cursor(array_points[i], mouse[0], mouse[1], finger);
                        flag[1] = true;
                    }
                    move(array_points[i]);
                }
                ctx.stroke();
            }, 1000/fps_loop);
        }
        function settings_realise(){
            limit_speed = +$('.limit_speed').val();
            force_visualisation = $('.force_visualisation').is(':checked');
            shuffle_distribution = $('.shuffle_distribution').is(':checked');
            shuffle_generation = $('.shuffle_generation').is(':checked');
            lineto = $('.lineto').is(':checked');
            border = $('.border').is(':checked');
            mass[0] = +$('.min_mass').val();
            mass[1] = +$('.max_mass').val();
            speed[0] = +$('.min_random_speed').val();
            speed[1] = +$('.max_random_speed').val();
            pxnpts = +$('.points_num').val();
            wall_decrement = +$('.wall_decrement').val();
            cursor_power = +$('.cursor_power').val();
            arrow_power = +$('.arrow_power').val();
            fps_loop = +$('.fps').val();
            spin_angle = +$('.spin_angle').val();
            gravity_resistance = +$('.gravity_resistance').val();
            color_a = $('.color_a').val().match(/[A-Za-z0-9]{2}/g).map(function(v) { return parseInt(v, 16) });
            color_b = $('.color_b').val().match(/[A-Za-z0-9]{2}/g).map(function(v) { return parseInt(v, 16) });
            line = $('.line').val();
            $('.canv').css('background', $('.background').val());
            $("#myModal").hide();
            $('.save_options').css('box-shadow', '');
            $('.save_remember').hide();
            Start();
        }
        function share(){
            var text = "https://shumik.site/archive/other/physics.php?shit=you";
            text += "&limit_speed=" + $('.limit_speed').val();
            text += "&force_visualisation=" + $('.force_visualisation').is(':checked');
            text += "&border=" + $('.border').is(':checked');
            text += "&shuffle_distribution=" + $('.shuffle_distribution').is(':checked');
            text += "&shuffle_generation=" + $('.shuffle_generation').is(':checked');
            text += "&lineto=" + $('.lineto').is(':checked');
            text += "&min_mass=" + $('.min_mass').val();
            text += "&max_mass=" + $('.max_mass').val();
            text += "&min_random_speed=" + $('.min_random_speed').val();
            text += "&max_random_speed=" + $('.max_random_speed').val();
            text += "&points_num=" + $('.points_num').val();
            text += "&wall_decrement=" + $('.wall_decrement').val();
            text += "&cursor_power=" + $('.cursor_power').val();
            text += "&arrow_power=" + $('.arrow_power').val();
            text += "&fps=" + $('.fps').val();
            text += "&spin_angle=" + $('.spin_angle').val();
            text += "&gravity_resistance=" + $('.gravity_resistance').val();
            text += "&color_a=" + encodeURIComponent($('.color_a').val());
            text += "&color_b=" + encodeURIComponent($('.color_b').val());
            text += "&background=" + encodeURIComponent($('.background').val());
            text += "&line=" + encodeURIComponent($('.line').val());
            navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
            $('.copy').addClass('btn-success');
            $('.copy').text('Copied');
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.copy').removeClass('btn-success');
                $('.copy').text('Share configuration ➥');
            }, 600);
        }
        function ResizeAll(){
            ww = window.innerWidth;
            wh = window.innerHeight;
            $('.canv').attr('width', ww);
            $('.canv').attr('height', wh);
        }
        function handleStart(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            var el = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var touches = evt.changedTouches;
            mouse = [touches[0].pageX, touches[0].pageY];
        }
        function handleMove(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            var el = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var touches = evt.changedTouches;
            mouse = [touches[0].pageX, touches[0].pageY];
        }
        function handleEnd(evt) {
            mouse = false;
        }
        function move_points_dist(one, mcursor){
            if(one){
                for (var i = 0; i < array_points.length; i++) {
                    array_points[i].x.pos = mcursor[0] + 0.001;
                    array_points[i].y.pos = mcursor[1];
                    array_points[i].x.speed = 0; 
                    array_points[i].x.delta = 0;
                    array_points[i].y.speed = 0; 
                    array_points[i].y.delta = 0;
                }
            }
            else{
                distribution.push([mcursor[0], mcursor[1]]);
                for (var i = 0; i < array_points.length; i++) {
                    var it = shuffle_distribution ? i%(distribution.length) : (Math.round(i/array_points.length*(distribution.length - 1)));
                    array_points[i].x.pos = distribution[it][0] + 0.001;
                    array_points[i].y.pos = distribution[it][1];
                    array_points[i].x.speed = 0; 
                    array_points[i].x.delta = 0;
                    array_points[i].y.speed = 0; 
                    array_points[i].y.delta = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            ResizeAll();
            settings_realise();
            $('body').dblclick(function(){
                fullScreen(this);
            });
            $(window).resize(function(){
                ResizeAll();
            });
            var el = document.getElementById("canvas");
              el.addEventListener("touchstart", handleStart, false);
              el.addEventListener("touchend", handleEnd, false);
              el.addEventListener("touchmove", handleMove, false);
            $("body").on("contextmenu", false);

            $(window).on('keydown', function (e) {
                //console.log(e.which);
                if (e.which == 32) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    inertion = !inertion;
                }
                else if (e.which == 82) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < array_points.length; i++) {
                        array_points[i].x.speed = -array_points[i].x.speed;
                        array_points[i].y.speed = -array_points[i].y.speed;
                    }
                }
                else if (e.which == 71 && e.ctrlKey) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    Start();
                }
                else if (e.which == 83 && e.ctrlKey) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $("#myModal").show();
                }
                else if(e.which == 72 && e.ctrlKey){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    alert('Mouse Left - pull'
                        +'\nMouce Right - push'
                        +'\nR - reverce speed'
                        +'\nSpace - inertion on/on'
                        +'\nMousewheel click - stop and move to cursor'
                        +'\nctrl(hold) + Mousewheel click/+move - distribute to multiplie points'
                        +'\nctrl + G - randomise'
                        +'\nctrl + S - settings'
                        +'\nDbl click - fullscreen'
                        +'\n↑ → ↓ ← /WASD - Move'
                        +'\nQ/E + Mouce - spin'
                        +'\nctrl + B - border off/on'
                        +'\nctrl + F - force visualisation off/on'
                        +'\nctrl + L - line connecting off/on'
                    );
                }
                else if(e.which == 66 && e.ctrlKey) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('.border').prop('checked', !$('.border').is(':checked'));
                    $('.border').change();
                }
                else if(e.which == 70 && e.ctrlKey) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('.force_visualisation').prop('checked', !$('.force_visualisation').is(':checked'));
                    $('.force_visualisation').change();
                }
                else if(e.which == 76 && e.ctrlKey) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('.lineto').prop('checked', !$('.lineto').is(':checked'));
                    $('.lineto').change();
                }
                else if (e.which == 38 || e.which == 87) {
                    arrows[0] = true;
                }
                else if (e.which == 39 || e.which == 68) {
                    arrows[1] = true;
                }
                else if (e.which == 40 || e.which == 83) {
                    arrows[2] = true;
                }
                else if (e.which == 37 || e.which == 65) {
                    arrows[3] = true;
                }
                else if(e.which == 81) {
                    spin = -spin_angle;
                }
                else if(e.which == 69) {
                    spin = spin_angle;
                }
            });
            $(window).on('keyup', function (e) {
                if (e.which == 38 || e.which == 87) {
                    arrows[0] = false;
                }
                else if (e.which == 39 || e.which == 68) {
                    arrows[1] = false;
                }
                else if (e.which == 40 || e.which == 83) {
                    arrows[2] = false;
                }
                else if (e.which == 37 || e.which == 65) {
                    arrows[3] = false;
                }
                else if(e.which == 81 && spin == -spin_angle) {
                    spin = 0;
                }
                else if(e.which == 69 && spin == spin_angle) {
                    spin = 0;
                }
                else if(e.which == 17){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    distribution = [];
                }
            });
            $('[data-dismiss=modal]').click(function(){
                $("#myModal").hide();
            });
            $('.canv').on('mousedown', function(event){
                //console.log(event);
                switch (event.which) {
                    case 1:
                        finger.val = cursor_power;
                        $('.canv').on('mousemove', function(event){
                            mouse = [event.offsetX, event.offsetY];
                        });
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        event.preventDefault();
                        if(event.ctrlKey){
                            move_points_dist(false, [event.offsetX, event.offsetY]);
                            $('.canv').on('mousemove', function(e2){
                                if(e2.ctrlKey){
                                    move_points_dist(false, [e2.offsetX, e2.offsetY]);
                                }
                            });
                            $('.canv').on('mouseup', function(){
                                $('.canv').off('mousemove');
                            });
                        }
                        else{
                            move_points_dist(true, [event.offsetX, event.offsetY]);
                        }
                        return;
                    case 3:
                        $('.canv').on('mousemove', function(event){
                            mouse = [event.offsetX, event.offsetY];
                        });
                        finger.val = -cursor_power;
                        break;
                    default:
                        return;
                }
                mouse = [event.offsetX, event.offsetY];
                $('.canv').on('mouseup', function(event){
                    //console.log(event.which);
                    switch (event.which) {
                        case 1:
                            if(finger.val == cursor_power){
                                mouse = false;
                                $('.canv').off('mousemove');
                            }
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            if(finger.val == -cursor_power){
                                mouse = false;
                                $('.canv').off('mousemove');
                                for (var i = 0; i < array_points.length; i++) {
                                    array_points[i].x.delta = 0;
                                    array_points[i].y.delta = 0;
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            return;
                    }
                });
            });
            $('.color_a').on('input', function(){
                color_a = $('.color_a').val().match(/[A-Za-z0-9]{2}/g).map(function(v) { return parseInt(v, 16) });
            });
            $('.color_b').on('input', function(){
                color_b = $('.color_b').val().match(/[A-Za-z0-9]{2}/g).map(function(v) { return parseInt(v, 16) });
            });
            $('.line').on('input', function(){
                line = $('.line').val();
            });
            $('.background').on('input', function(){
                $('.canv').css('background', $('.background').val());
            });
            $('.force_visualisation').change(function(){
                force_visualisation = $(this).is(':checked');
            });
            $('.border').change(function(){
                border = $(this).is(':checked');
            });
            $('.lineto').change(function(){
                lineto = $(this).is(':checked');
            });
            $('.shuffle_distribution').change(function(){
                shuffle_distribution = $(this).is(':checked');
            });
            $('.wall_decrement').change(function(){
                wall_decrement = +$(this).val();
            });
            $('.cursor_power').change(function(){
                cursor_power = +$(this).val();
            });
            $('.arrow_power').change(function(){
                arrow_power = +$(this).val();
            });
            $('.gravity_resistance').change(function(){
                gravity_resistance = +$(this).val();
            });
            $('.spin_angle').change(function(){
                spin_angle = +$(this).val();
            });
            $('.limit_speed').change(function(){
                limit_speed = +$(this).val();
            });
            $('input').on('input', function(){
                if (!$(this).is('[no-save]')){
                    $('.save_options').css('box-shadow', '0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(225,83,97,.5)');
                    $('.save_remember').show();
                }
            });
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
        });
```

```css
body{
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        *[unselectable=on] { 
            -moz-user-select: none; 
            -o-user-select:none; 
            -khtml-user-select: none; 
            -webkit-user-select: none; 
            -ms-user-select: none; 
            user-select: none; 
        }
        @media (min-width: 576px){
            .modal-dialog {
                max-width: 550px;
            }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TS | Gravity</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas class="canv" id="canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: auto; background-color: black; cursor: crosshair;" width="ww" height="wh"></canvas>
    <div class="modal" id="myModal" style="background: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.7);">
        <div class="modal-dialog" style="max-width: 700px;">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header" style="border: none;">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Settings: <span class="btn-warning">be carefull</span> <span class="btn-danger save_remember" style="display: none;">Click "Save" to see changes</span></h4> 
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body row" style="padding: 0px; margin: 5px; max-height: 50vh; overflow-x: auto;">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input type="checkbox" no-save class="form-check-input force_visualisation" >Force visualisation
                            </label>
                            <br>
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input type="checkbox" no-save class="form-check-input border" checked>Border
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input type="checkbox" no-save class="form-check-input shuffle_distribution" checked>Shuffle distribution
                            </label>
                            <br>
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input type="checkbox" no-save class="form-check-input lineto" >Line connecting
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input shuffle_generation" checked>Shuffle generation
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12"><hr></div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                      <label>◦ Min mass:</label>
                      <input type="number" value="0.5" class="form-control min_mass">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                      <label>⦿ Max mass:</label>
                      <input type="number" value="1.2" class="form-control max_mass">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                      <label>⥇Limit speed:</label>
                      <input type="number" no-save value="20" class="form-control limit_speed">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                      <label>➧ Min start speed:</label>
                      <input type="number" value="-4" class="form-control min_random_speed">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                      <label>➠ Max start speed:</label>
                      <input type="number" value="4" class="form-control max_random_speed">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                      <label>░ Screen px/point:</label>
                      <input type="number" value="700" class="form-control points_num">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                      <label>↸ Wall decrement:</label>
                      <input type="number" no-save value="0.8" class="form-control wall_decrement">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                      <label>✺ Cursor/Arrows power:</label>
                      <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="number" no-save value="0.2" class="form-control cursor_power">
                        <input type="number" no-save value="0.2" class="form-control arrow_power">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                      <label>⫷ Gravity resistance:</label>
                      <input type="number" no-save value="2" class="form-control gravity_resistance">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                      <label>⚠️ FPS:</label>
                      <input type="number" value="60" class="form-control fps">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                      <label>✏ Min/Max/Back/Line:</label>
                      <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="color" no-save value="#0000ff" class="form-control color_b">
                        <input type="color" no-save value="#ff0000" class="form-control color_a">
                        <input type="color" no-save value="#000000" class="form-control background">
                        <input type="color" no-save value="#1c1c1c" class="form-control line">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                      <label>∠ Spin angle:</label>
                      <input type="number" no-save value="13" class="form-control spin_angle">
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary copy" onclick="share()">Share configuration ➥</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success save_options" onclick="settings_realise()">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

кол-во точек можно задать в настройках (ctrl + S) в поле px/point чем меньше число тем больше точек.

Но проблема в том, что нельзя задать их большое количество, резко падает fps. Это странно, так как в браузере нормально работают даже 3d игры с +- нормальной графикой, а тут просто много точек отрисовать не может. Провел опыты, фпс зависит ТОЛЬКО от одной строчки ctx.fillRect(...), которая больше не вызывает никаких функций внутри. Подозреваю что проблема в том что отрисовка делается процессором а не видеокартой, но я в этом не специалист. Подскажите пожалуйста, какие еще могут быть способ повторить такой эффект, но чтобы работал более оптимизировано.

Comment: В играх 100500 различных оптимизаций, что выходит за рамки ответа - написаны целые книги и движки.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko я не об полигонах, освещении и расчетах, а только о точке и одной функции

Comment: Попробуйте использовать подходящие для этого библиотеки, например pixi.js

Comment: Даже для точки есть оптимизации, почитайте например про [двойную буферизацию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F).